# What is the correct way to denote a coordinate system in writing?

Tags: geometry

I want a systematic way that is readable but also mathematically rigorous for defining a coordinate system in writing. For example for a cartesian coordinate system centered on the fixed or moving point $O$, I have seen people write $(O;X,Y,Z)$ Would this be correct?

Furthermore, what is then the best way to denote that a point $\mathbf{x}$ is defined in this particular coordinate system?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. The usual way to define a 3-dimensional space would be to just use $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I'm not sure what relevance the $O$ you're using has unless you're embedded in a pre-existing space. And as for denoting that $x$ is in the space, if your space is called $X$, just say $x \in X$.

Comment: Im not asking how to define a 3d space; I am asking how to best denote a particular coordinate system in that space. Specifically this means how to describe a point's $\mathbf{x}$ location using the triple $(X,Y,Z)$ with reference to some point in that space. I'm just interested in the notation people use to denote different coordinate systems in the same space.

Comment: Oh! I see now. The most sensible thing in my opinion would be to say $X$ and $Y$ are both $\mathbb{R}^3$, then define a function $f:X \mapsto Y$ such that $f:(x,y,z)\mapsto (x-x_O, y-y_O, z-z_O)$. And you could then say $x \in Y$ to denote that the point is described by the new coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a lot of correct ways to do so, it is just a matter of convention.
The two most common ways to do it (in my experience) are this one and (O;i,j,k) with i,j and k as vertices.

Also, a way (but again, just a matter of convention) to indicate in which system a point is defined is to write the system at the bottom right of the coordinates, something like that :
(x,y,z)<sub>(O;X,Y,Z)</sub>